# When is $c v^\top y y^\top v \ge ||v||^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, normed-spaces

Given $c\in R$ being some constant, $v, y \in R^n$, I want to find conditions for which the following inequality holds true:
$$c v^\top y y^\top v \ge ||v||^2$$

EDIT: 
Note that $y y^\top$ is an $n \times n$ matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the product is written, $v^\top y^\top y v$ must be parsed as $v^\top (y^\top y) v$ since the products $v^\top y^\top$ and $yv$ don't make sense. Since $y^\top y = \|y\|^2$ this leads to $c \|v\|^2 \|y\|^2 \ge \|v\|^2$. The condition is $\|v\|= 0$ or $c \|y\|^2 \ge 1$.

Comment: Thanks, Umberto. I just noted that there was a mistake in the transpose. I actually have a matrix with y y^\top.

Comment: After the edit, the product $y^\top v$ is a real number: the inner product $\langle y,v \rangle$. The condition you need is that $c \langle y,v \rangle^2 \ge \|v\|^2$. There are lots of ways to interpret this.